# Redirecting a http request including headers - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So i want to test a local version of a webserver. But i want to use the website to do so.

Im looking to make a chrome extension to redirect a http (POST & GET) request and sent it to localhost:8020

I have currently achieved this, but i dont see how its possible to also include the header in this request.

There are two eventListeners (onBeforeRequest and onBeforeSendHeaders) and i need the behaviour of both. onBeforeRequest does not send the headers when redirecting, and with onBeforeSendHeaders you cannot redirect.

Anyone know the best solution?

I've tried using onBeforeSendHeaders and then creating a new XMLHttpRequest, but im forbid from setting most the headers i need.

Comment: In onBeforeSendHeaders you would modify the requestHeaders array as shown in various answers and examples, there's no need to construct a new XHR. I would also check if there's a separate external utility that can redirect requests to a local URL:port.

Comment: Theres no way of changing the host via the header though.

Comment: You need both events of course. My comment doesn't contradict that.